# System.Data.OracleClient migration to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess - ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0, database-connection, odp.net

Introduction:

I'm currently working on a MVC 4 application that uses Microsoft's OracleClient dll. I'm now planning on migrating to Oracle's ManagedDatAccess.dll.

Steps I took according to information provided by Oracle.

> Replaced all the mentions of OracleClient.

```
//ie removed using System.Data.OracleClient
//added
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
```

> Updated all my oracle types to the new one.

```
//ie removed public OracleType typeOracle { get; set; }
//added
public OracleDbType typeOracle { get; set; }
```

> Configured Web.config

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <LDAPsettings>
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVERS" value="(oidserverver.domain.com:3060:3131)" />
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE" value="oid" />
        <LDAPsetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT" value="dc=domain,dc=com" />
      </LDAPsettings>
      <settings>
        <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="(TNSNAMES, LDAP)" />
        <setting name ="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\app\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin" />
      </settings>
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

> I then try to run my application but get the following exceptions:

```
[NetworkException (0x30f9): ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file]
[OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file]
```

> It happened right when I try to open the connection:

```
    private void setConnection()
    {
        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = _OracleConnectionString;
        }

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open(); // Throws exception here.
        }
    }
```

I'm a fairly new programmer, if possible please be specific with what steps I should take.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled oracle 12 client on my machine.

So much for standalone....